# Is there a quicker way for me to give items to other characters?

Tags: day-of-the-tentacle

When playing through the game you often need to send an item to another time zone through the Chron-O-John.  This can get tedious when you need to travel through several rooms with each character to make the exchange.  More so when Laverne needs to decide if she is ill or needs to visit the toilet as an excuse before getting the tentacle outfit.

Is there a quicker way to swapping items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give an item to another character through the interface.  Press the Give button, select an item and then the character's face on the right hand side.  This cuts out all the walking/excuses when all you want to do is hand an item over to another character.

Comment: You don't even need to select give, simply clicking on the item (which defaults to Use) and clicking on the other characters portrait wil send it.